# Why argparse do not accept arguments and prints new "magic" usage?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, argparse

I wrote a small python script using argparse to deal with commandlineoptions.
It already worked until it suddenly behaves very strange.
Now it sometimes rejects my arguments and prints me a different usage.
I run it on Windows 8.1 using python3.4
Anyone has an idea what can create such a problem?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Encodes or decodes a file or folder.")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--encode", action="store_true", help="Specify mode: encode")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--decode", action="store_true", help="Specify mode: decode")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", action="store", metavar="password", help="Specify password.")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", help="Specify file/folder.")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", action="store_true", help="Runs unittests.")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

[image: Consolelog]

**UPDATE**

in case of -t the following code was executed:

```
testMode = args["test"]
#...
if (testMode):
    unittest.main()#this produced the error
    input("Press Enter to leave")
    exit()
```

Solution:

```
testMode = args["test"]
#...
if (testMode):
    unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]])
    input("Press Enter to leave")
    exit()
```

Comment: What does your code do with `args.t`?

Comment: I already solved it myself, I just cant accept it in the first 24 hours. The complete post is just for others who may run in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of -t a unittest was started:

```
unittest.main()
```

this produced the new usage message because it was also using argv
to fix it use

```
unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]])
```